# Set first array value to default attributes in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce insert product programmatically using my own php, to insert variation I'm using update_post_meta to insert variation :

```
// set variation
    $data = array (
        "ukuran" => "S,M,L,XL",
        "price" => 100000
    );

    if (isset($data['ukuran']) && count(explode(",", $data['ukuran'])) > 1){
        $attr_label = 'Ukuran';
        $attr_slug = sanitize_title($attr_label);

        $att_ukuran = str_replace(',', '|', $data['ukuran']);
        $attributes_array[$attr_slug] = array(
            'name' => $attr_label,
            'value' => $att_ukuran, // example : "a|b|c"
            'is_visible' => '1',
            'is_variation' => '1',
            'is_taxonomy' => '0' // for some reason, this is really important       
        );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', $attributes_array );

        $parent_id = $post_id;
        $variation = array(
            'post_title'   => $article_name . ' (variation)',
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_parent'  => $parent_id,
            'post_type'    => 'product_variation'
        );

        foreach(explode(",", $data['ukuran']) as $new_ukuran){
            $variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation );
            update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', $data['price'] );
            update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', $data['price'] );
            // update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_stock_qty', 10 );
            update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_' . $attr_slug, $new_ukuran );
            WC_Product_Variable::sync( $parent_id );
        }
    }
```

but I want to set default varation for it, how I can do that ? I try

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_default_attributes', $attributes_array);
```

but not working, I try many times and I failed.

Comment: hope some want can help...

Comment: What are the names of your attributes? Normally attributes are store as `default_attribute_attribute_name`

Comment: Not working sir.

Comment: what did u use? whats your attribute names?

Comment: ukuran attribute name

Comment: I havebeen edit my script, please see

Comment: First since Woocommerce 3, your code is outdated, with mistakes… This is not enough and not testable… You are not explaining the context and you should give all related code in your question (or if you are using existing StackOverFlow answers code, you should always add the thread links in your question.

Comment: Hi, thats all code i give, what kind all related code ?